# How do I display the "recently created node" block using Views?

Tags: 6, views

I am trying to show the recently added content data in a block, using the Views module, but I can't see any record even if I recently added some nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the views output settings. Notice there is a preview option. You wrongly select either fields either the filter doesn't match. You need to filter by Content Date Field and order it desc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I guess you are having problem with the content type selection. Use the right content type in the Filter criteria ( Content: Type= xxxxx) where xxxxx is your content type you are working with or created for the node. While Field display is set to fields.

Answer (score 0):

1. check *Filters*
2. If you have set *display* to *fields*, Don't forget to add some fields in the *Fields* section

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be within the views settings. Please check whether your content which you want to see is published or not and the permissions for different users to see the content. If that is not the case, check what Content Type you are selecting in the view..it should appear in left hand side once you are in the view settings...you should be able to follow from there onwards...also, check what field you have added, if you haven't then add them of type content:node